# JavaScript switch comparison not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery:

```js
var Page = parseInt($(".active_pagination").data("number"));
   var First = parseInt($(".pagination_number:first").data("number"));
   var Last = parseInt($(".pagination_number:last").data("number"));
   alert("Page: "+Page+" First: "+First+" Last: "+Last);
   switch(Page){
    case (Page === First):
        alert("First");
        $(".prev").closest('li').hide();
        $(".next").closest('li').show();
    break;
    case (Page === Last):
        alert("Last");
        $(".prev").closest('li').show();
        $(".next").closest('li').hide();
    break;
    default:
        alert("Default");
        $(".prev").closest('li').show();
        $(".next").closest('li').show();
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number active_pagination" data-number="1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="4">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="5">5</a></li>
```

I parsed all variables as Int and then executed comparison but it still doesn't work. I don't know how it is continuously executing default condition.

Comment: Use `case First:` and `case Last:`

Comment: `Page === First` is either `true` or `false`; `Page` is `1`, or `2`, or `3`... `switch(Page)...case(Page===First)` compares `Page` and `Page===First`. It's safe to say `1` (or `2`, or `3`...) is not equal to `false`, nor to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In switch case block you actually need to set the conditional statements based on the value of the variable that is used inside the `switch` parameter.

```js
var Page = parseInt($(".active_pagination").data("number"));
   var First = parseInt($(".pagination_number:first").data("number"));
   var Last = parseInt($(".pagination_number:last").data("number"));
   alert("Page: "+Page+" First: "+First+" Last: "+Last);
   switch(Page){
    case (First):
        alert("First");
        $(".prev").closest('li').hide();
        $(".next").closest('li').show();
    break;
    case (Last):
        alert("Last");
        $(".prev").closest('li').show();
        $(".next").closest('li').hide();
    break;
    default:
        alert("Default");
        $(".prev").closest('li').show();
        $(".next").closest('li').show();
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number active_pagination" data-number="1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="4">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pagination_list pagination_number" data-number="5">5</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your switch with

```
switch(Page){
        case First:
            alert("First");
            $(".prev").closest('li').hide();
            $(".next").closest('li').show();
            break;
        case Last:
            alert("Last");
            $(".prev").closest('li').show();
            $(".next").closest('li').hide();
            break;
        default:
            alert("Default");
            $(".prev").closest('li').show();
            $(".next").closest('li').show();
    }
```

`switch` implicitly checks for equality with the cases specified, you don't do the comparison yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1

```
switch (Page) {

    case First:

        alert("First");

        break;

    case Last:

        alert("Last");

        break;

    default:

        alert("Default");

}
```

Method 2

```
    if(Page === First){

        alert("First");

    }

    else if (Page === Last){

        alert("Last");

   }else {

        alert("Default");

   }
```